# Склонение выражения "синий чулок"

Tags: склонение

Как правильно будет в родительном падеже множественного числа: синих чулок или синих чулков, - если под этим выражением имеются в виду не предметы туалета, а женщины?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если это не о паре чулок синего цвета, а о персонах, то "чулков" (если без самого выражения не обойтись). Похожие изменения при переходе к множественному числу происходят, например, в словосочетаниях "сыны отечества" (вместо "сыновья") и "учёные мужи" (не "мужья"). Этим проводится грань между буквальным и метафорическим смыслом слова.

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ!